# Fluid simulation sticking through mesh

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm having an issue with my fluid simulations. I'm a beginner, so I might be missing something obvious.

I'm trying to fill up a cup with water, but the liquid is behaving very strangely (see below).

Most of my settings are default, except the cup's volume init is shell and the slip type is free slip (to prevent sticking). I've made the problem less severe by increasing the resolution of the simulation, but it still sticks out of the cup.

[image: MY issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution is still too small. You should try at least doubling "Final", and setting "Viewport Display" to "Final" too.

Any obstacle which has a width smaller or comparable with the voxel size is likely to be ignored by the simulation. In your case the voxel size (domain size, divided by resolution) is too big!

[image]

If the problem persists after increasing the resolution, check that the normals on your obstacle object are facing outwards (in Edit Mode: select all with <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in Blender 2.8+)

Comment: This definitely seems to be my problem. However, I've cranked the resolution up to 200, making the bake time grind to a halt. And there are still a small amount of fluid poking through. Nevertheless, thank you very much!